# Validate date range based on additional parameter

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I am working on requirement where I need to validate the difference between two dates based on third parameter.

Requirement :

- EndDate should not be more than 14 days from the start date.
- If extension is given endDate should not be more than 28 days from
  the start date.
- If end date or start date equals to "NA"(no value) then I dont need
  to perform validation

I have written below code but it is not giving perfect results in testing.Please help me in correcting this code .

```
public static boolean validateDateRange(String startDate,String EndDate,String extension){  
        if(startDate.equals("NA")||EndDate.equals("NA")){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            boolean x=false;
            if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
                x=true;
            }
                Date d1 = null;
                Date d2 = null;
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                try {
                    d1 = format.parse(startDate);
                    d2 = format.parse(EndDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                long diff = d2.getTime()- d1.getTime();//in Milli seconds
                long numOfDays = diff/(1000*60*60*24);
                System.out.println(numOfDays);
                if(numOfDays >14&&(x&&numOfDays>28)){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    return true;
                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have modified the above condition like this and its working..Please suggest improvements.....if((!x&&numOfDays >14)||(x&&numOfDays>28)){
        return false;
       }
       else{
        return true;
       }

Comment: You don't need `x&&` in the second part of the condition (after the or) because the method should always return `false` if the difference is greater than 28 (according to your explanation, please correct me if I am wrong). Also note that, if you change this, `x` is only used once, so you don't need the variable anymore. The final `if` statement can therefore be changed to `if (numOfDays > 28 || (!extension.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && numOfDays > 14))` (not tested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, just removed some redundant `if`'s. You should, however, rethink what happens when an exception occurs. It does not make much sense to continue processing in this case. The return value should probably be `true` in this case, since you do not want anyone to get fined on account of a system error. Maybe even rethrow the exception?

```
public static boolean validateDateRange(String startDate,String EndDate,String extension){  
    if(startDate.equals("NA")||EndDate.equals("NA")){
        return true;
    }

    boolean x = extension.equalsIgnoreCase("Y");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    try {
        d1 = format.parse(startDate);
        d2 = format.parse(EndDate);
        long diff = d2.getTime()- d1.getTime();//in Milli seconds
        long numOfDays = diff/(1000*60*60*24);
        System.out.println(numOfDays);

        return !((!x && numOfDays > 14) || numOfDays > 28);
    } catch (ParseException e) { // maybe rethrow exception?
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```